# Getting custom CacheItems from MemoryCache

Tags: c#, .net, memorycache

I'm implementing a MemoryCache with a derived CacheItem, but having difficulty interacting with it once it's in the cache. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MemoryCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        CustomCacheItem someItem = (CustomCacheItem)cache.AddOrGetExisting(new CustomCacheItem(1, "tacos", "waffles"), policy);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class CustomCacheItem : CacheItem
{
    public int FailureCt { get; set; }

    public CustomCacheItem(int _failureCt, string _key, string _value)
        : base(_key, _value)
    {
        FailureCt = _failureCt;
    }
}
```

This throws an error of `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Runtime.Caching.CacheItem' to type 'CacheTest.CustomCacheItem'.` which sort of makes sense; maybe it doesn't retain the information about the cache item put in. But if so, how do I get my custom cache item out? How do I interact with that property (in this case `FailureCt`) if the return value is of the generic base type?

Comment: What is the purpose of deriving from CacheItem? CacheItem just serves as an entry into the cache and a wrapper around your data.  `CacheItem item = (CacheItem)cache.AddOrGetExisting(new CacheItem(1, "tacos", "waffles"), policy);`       item.value would give you the data back.  **note that as the docs state, this will return null if the key exists** [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988741.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988741.aspx)

Comment: @hdz Yeah, I think I had a faulty assumption on how CacheItem was used in the greater cache structure. I thought all the extra information was stored along with it, but it seems like that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `MemoryCache.AddOrGetExisting(CacheItem, CacheItemPolicy)` is creating a new `CacheItem` internally:

```
public override CacheItem AddOrGetExisting(CacheItem item, CacheItemPolicy policy)
{
    if (item == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
    return new CacheItem(item.Key, AddOrGetExistingInternal(item.Key, item.Value, policy));
}
```

[MemoryCache source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCache.cs,cee1cc9941a1c7f9,references)

---

I'd recommend storing `FailureCt` in the value itself and not in the `CacheItem` wrapper:

```
public class CacheValue
{
    public int FailureCt { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
CacheValue someItem = (CacheValue)cache.AddOrGetExisting("tacos", new CacheValue()
{
    FailureCt = 1,
    Value = "waffles"
}, policy);
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. I guess I had a faulty assumption that CacheItem was what I should be overriding, rather than just the value. Thanks!